# Communication between AccesibilityService and Activity

Tags: android

I'm looking for an answer for my question, and I have not found it anywhere.

I have an AccesibilityService running, and I want to send information from it to the MainActivity.

I have been trying to do it with the Messenger class, but I can't.

Can anyone help me to do it?

I have put this code in the mainactivity:

```
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
        switch (msg.what) {
        case NoficationService.MSG_ENCENDER:
            // Envía "1".
            String message = "1";
            mApp1.sendData(message);
            break;
        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

In the MainActivity I have this code:

```
try {
            Message msg = Message.obtain(null, NoficationService.MSG_ENCENDER, 0, 0);
            msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
            mService.send(msg);
            Log.d(tag, "Enviado Msg");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.d(tag, "Excepción Msg");
        }
```

Waiting for your help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use broadcasts:

```
public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.packegeName";
```

1) register broadcast in your activity:

```
BroadcastReceiver  br = new BroadcastReceiver() {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // proccess messages
}
}


IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION); 
registerReceiver(br, intFilt);
```

2) Send broadcast from AccesibilityService

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);
intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PARAM_STATUS, MainActivity.STATUS_FINISH);
intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PARAM_RESULT, time * 100);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```